# Reroute dynamically in codeigniter routes file

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have the following URL which will work :

www.example.com/police/alarm/5

However, in my database i have a table with some name values, one of the values is 'car'.

I want to dynamically route my url that if one of the name values is the first segment in my URL, ignore it and reroute without it. (I will set some variables based on this value in my constants file).

The code I have so far in my routes.php file is:

```
require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB.php');
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->where('org_type', 2)
    ->get('organization');
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[ $row->name.'/:any' ]         = '$1';
}
```

This gives me the following result (doing a var_dump):

```
D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\codeigniter\application\config\routes.php:76:
array (size=11)
  'default_controller' => string 'home' (length=4)
  '404_override' => string 'error/my404' (length=11)
  'translate_uri_dashes' => boolean false
  'login' => string 'auth/login' (length=10)
  'recoverAccount' => string 'auth/recover' (length=12)
  'car/:any' => string '$1' (length=2)
  'truck/:any' => string '$1' (length=2)
```

When I browse to an url containing 'car' or 'truck' as the first part in my URL, it does not reroute to the url without it.

edit:

```
$route[ $row->name.'/:any' ]
or
$route[ $row->name.'/(:any)' ]
```

result is still the same

Comment: As a test, does it work as expected if you hard-code them in?

Comment: Yes, when hardcoded it works flawlessly

Comment: `$route[ $row->name.'/:any' ]         = '$1';` means you have almost infinite (as many as rows in DB) controller files since first parameter `$1` is recognised as controller by CodeIgniter. You should have something like `controller_name/$1`. Show us your controller code.

Comment: the controller name is always the 2nd part of the URL, i cannot put it to a fixed name since i have more than one controller.. my only requirement is to skip the first part of the URL (e.g. 'car') and then just execute the controller name (which is the 2nd part)